# Retrieve the string “0.1” from after assignment to a double variable

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion, precision, arbitrary-precision

I have a naive question about the high-precision number conversion (in C++ here).

Suppose the user assigns 0.1 to the double variable x_d with this statement,

```
x_d = 0.1
```

It is known that `x_d` thus obtained is no more exactly `0.1`, due to the inevitable machine rounding.

I wonder whether we still have a way to get back the original highly precise string “0.1”,  from the double variable `x_d`? Clearly, it is useless to use `std::to_string (x_d)` here. Even a high precision library like `boost::multiprecision` or MPFR seem to be helpless. For example,  `std::to_string(boost:cpp_dec_float_10000(x_d) )` cannot recover back the lost precision.

So my question is, can we retrieve back the string “0.1” from a double `x_d` that is assigned using the statement `x_d = 0.1`?

Comment: "I wonder whether we still have a way to get back the original highly precise string “0.1”". `0.1` has one (count them) significant digit. What's so precise about it? `0.10000000000000` would be highly precise. No, we cannot get back 1/10 from a double, just like we cannot get 1/3 back from 0.3333333333.... with *any* finite number of 3s.

Comment: Not possible with double or float. You can write a custom CDouble class that stores in BCD.

Comment: @n.m  Try "std::cout.precision(20); std::cout<<"x_d = " <<x_d <<std::endl; "

Comment: @zell I know what it would print. You can print a diameter of the visible Universe as 13008226600000000000 mm. What would be the point of it? You print with precision your data actually has, not with whatever precision it can be represented in your hardware.

Comment: @n.m. I see your point. Thank you. In my problem setting, we consider the precision difference between a machine and the ideal mathematical representation of numbers.

Comment: Machine numbers can only exactly represent a finite subset of mathematical numbers. With most hardware implementations 0.1 is not in this subset. If you need some kind of exact mathematical numbers, e.g. rationals, or decimal fractions (i.e. rationals with the denominator of 10^n) you have to use a class designed for such data.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that during the assignment, the decimal number 0.1 is rounded to a double value `X` that does not equal the decimal number 0.1. Now, assume some other computation results in the value`X`, but without it being rounded. In order to distinguish those two, you would have to store the origin somewhere. For that, there is simply no place in a double (assuming common implementations), so the answer to your question is "no".